# prove that $a!b! \mid(a,b)(a+b-1)!$ where $a,b$ are positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that it can be proved by the divisible algorithm but how to proceed as if $a!b!{\,|\,}(a+b-1)!$ so this means $a!b!{\,|\,}a$ and $a!b!{\,|\,}b$ 
and also it will divide $1$ so this means $a!b!=1$ otherwise it will not divide $1$.

Is my proceed is in right direction?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want to prove?

Comment: I want to prove the above result

Comment: Those fraction bars were presumably intended as divisibility symbols. But surely you are aware that the notation for the divisibility symbol is a _vertical_ bar, not a slash. In MathJax, you can use \mid.

Comment: @Palautot Ka: I don't think your edit is correct.

Comment: @quasi Thanks for reminding me....

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to prove
$$a!b!\mid(a,b)(a+b-1)!\tag{1}$$
where $(a,b)=\gcd(a,b)$. Using Bezout's identity, this will follow
if we can prove both
$$a!b!\mid a(a+b-1)!\tag{2}$$
and
$$a!b!\mid b(a+b-1)!.\tag{3}$$
These are similar, so just consider $(2)$. This is equivalent to
$$(a-1)!b!\mid (a+b-1)!$$
which is true, as the binomial coefficient $\binom{a+b-1}{a-1}$
is an integer.

Comment: By "Bezout's identity" do you mean the fact that any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides $\gcd(a,b)$ (which indeed can be deduced from $\gcd(a,b)\in a\Bbb Z+b\Bbb Z$)?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen exactly!